# External JS in simplemodal

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Iam successfully loading an external html-code in a modal window. But there is a JS in this external code, which i need to execute. I do not know in advance, which JS comes with external code. So I can not take advantage of onShow method. How can I execute the code that comes with an external html?

FOR EXAMPLE
I need to bind submit function to form wich comes with external html

Comment: Can you give us an example? Perhaps make a jsfiddle or jsbin. It would make your question more solid and easier to answer. Not to mention, we can edit your example to work, thereby showing you exactly how to make it work in your situation.

Comment: This is a source code:http://jsfiddle.net/FjJ56/ and this is an external code: http://jsfiddle.net/XEbPU/ There is an duplicate JS code in both variants. Firts is what simplemodal suggests. And the second is what i need - when JS code executes within external html code

Comment: Is any one know, how to force modal window to execute ajax-loaded js-scripts in the same flow as html rendering? (it is seems to be executed before that html rendered. That is why jquery can not bind events at undefined elements)